# Google map in html. Can't display map

Tags: javascript, html

I have problems with displaying the google map. I did all in google api manager (key etc). But I have problem now with my javascript/html code:

Here is console error:- 
[image]

Here is fragment code html:-

```
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height: 300px;"></div>

    <form id="mapForm" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form" placeholder="Gdzie jesteś?">
        </div>  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pokaż trasę</button>
        <button id="findPosition" class="btn btn-info hidden" title="Wykryj moją lokalizację">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
<script async defer src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB0QcbklwQFRlSb4-Y3wFS2_QAVh0omNTY&language=pl&callback=init"></script>
```

And JS code below:-

```
(function(){

var map = {

    makeMap: function() {

        var loc = this.location.split(","),
            pos = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center:pos,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        this.mapObj = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#map"), mapOptions);
    },

    init: function(options){

        if(!options.location) return;

        try { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", this.makeMap.bind(this)); } catch(e) { return; } );

        this.options = options;
        this.location = this.options.location;
    }
}
map.init({
    location: "52.6884592,28.7404605",
    mapMarker: "img/map_marker.png"
});
})();
```

How can I display this map? Realy thank you for any answers:-*

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. You haven't posted your API include and the posted code contains syntax errors (extra ")")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This code :

```
function initMap() {
var myLatLng = {
    lat: 52.6884592,
    lng: 28.7404605
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
});
var ico = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png'
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: ico,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

}

Comment: but i still have problem with callback: <script async defer src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB0QcbklwQFRlSb4-Y3wFS2_QAVh0omNTY&language=pl&callback=initMap"></script> -- i have this function in another file geo-google-map.js

Answer (score 1):

Use can do in this way :

```
 function initMap() {
 var myLatLng = {
     lat: 52.6884592,
     lng: 28.7404605
 };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 4,
     center: myLatLng
 });

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     title: 'Hello World!'
 });
```

}

Comment: Hey Giacomo i posted another answer it will solve your problem.